# Images not loading from local Strapi server using NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, strapi

So I've been stuck on this problem and looking for solutions for almost a day now.
I'm running Strapi locally, and migrated my hobby project from React to NextJS.

[image]

In this picture, I'm loading the data from the Strapi server running locally. The title, description and pictures are being delivered flawlessly, but unfortuantely I couldn't load the images no matter what I tried. I have a 400 error in the console as well.

Console error is this:

`GET http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=%2Fuploads%2Fsmall_113631705_1467164123471551_2603152321747988104_n_a594b15e6c.jpg&w=384&q=75 400 (Bad Request)`
When I console log the data, I can see everything coming as it's supposed to.
In the `next.config.js` I tried adding the following:

```
const nextConfig = {
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: "http",
                hostname: "0.0.0.0",
                port: "1337",
                pathname: "",
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

and I tried to change the hostname and path name, but no luck.
Can someone tell me what I'm missing here as I'm new to Next and Strapi.
Thanks.